# Propertly break down and pass data between views

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I'm still learning Swift and I wanted to cleanup some code and break down views, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass data between views, so I wanted to reach out and check with others.

So let's say that I have `MainView()` which previously had this:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    
    if let item = model.selectedItem {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 3) {
            Text(item.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I created a `SecondView()` and changed the `MainView()` content to this:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    
    if let item = model.selectedItem {
        SecondView(item: item)
    }
}
```

Inside `SecondView()`, how can I access the `item` data so that I can use `item.title` inside `SecondView()` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass `item` to `SecondView`, declare `item` as a `let` property and then when you call it with `SecondView(item: item)`, `SecondView` can refer to `item.title`.

Here is a complete example expanding on your code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item {
    let title = "Test Title"
}

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItem: Item? = Item()
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
 
    var body: some View {
        if let item = model.selectedItem {
            SecondView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.title)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        MainView(model: model)
    }
}
```